# Restoring an Xcode version project

Tags: ios, xcode

The Xcode project I'm using now is a little messed up. My IOS Game version now that I'm working on is 1.1.0, and the one before was 1.0.5. The previous version was normal, and the main thing that I'm only changing now is importing ads. But I don't know how I can restore the version since Xcode automatically saves the project itself. Is there an easy way to do this?

Side Note: I'm using XCode 8.2.1

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an easy way to do this?

If you're using git it's trivial.

If you're not using any source control it's likely impossible; you might be able to get something out of Time Machine but as a substitute for true source control that's just rolling the dice.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misreading this, you seem to be asking how to manually set your project's version, which is simple.

Select your project at the top of the Project Navigator, and in the General tab, the Identity section is where you set your version.

**Edit:** Apparently, you were talking about version control, in which case you need to check whether you created a local git repository when you first created the Xcode project (the checkbox may have been checked by default).

You can do this by navigating to your project directory in Terminal and performing the `git status` command there.

Comment: I know how to do that, I'm just trying to bring back every single code and file from the previous version of the project.

Comment: @JosephCarroll Edited my response accordingly. You should check, since there's a good chance Xcode did create a repository when you first created your project.

Comment: @Foefirelord fat lot of good, if he never did a commit. They don't happen by themselves.